# Junit integration testcase fails to compare the dates in dao layer

Tags: java, spring, junit, integration-testing

I'm facing the issue while executing the integration testcase. As per the below query, there is date comparison. When this query is executed by testcase, it returns the zero result. The moment i remove the where condition from the query it returns the correct result as 2.  To dig in further, in my testcase i fetched the employees first and verified that they have correct date and satisfy the where condition. But I'm still confused, when this check fails in DAO layer via Integration testcase.

Below is the EmployeeDAOImpl class

```
private static final String EMP_COUNT_BY_COMPANY_QUERY = "select count(employeeid) from ref_employee e join txn_user u on (e.createdby=u.userid and u.companyid = :companyId) where e.createddate between :startDate and :endDate";

@Override
    public Long getEmpCountByCompany(Long companyId) {
        BigInteger recordCount = (BigInteger) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
            @Override
            public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(EMP_COUNT_BY_COMPANY_QUERY);
                sqlQuery.setParameter("companyId", companyId);
                sqlQuery.setParameter("startDate", getStartOfCurrentDate());
                sqlQuery.setParameter("endDate", getEndOfCurrentDate());
                return sqlQuery.uniqueResult();
            }
        });
        return recordCount.longValue();
    }
private Date getEndOfCurrentDate() {
        Date end = DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), 1);
        return DateUtils.truncate(end , Calendar.DATE);
    }
private Date getStartOfCurrentDate() {
        return DateUtils.truncate(new Date(), Calendar.DATE);
    }
```

Below is the employeeServiceClass

```
@Override
    public Long getEmpCountByCompany(Long companyId) {
        return empDao.getEmpCountByCompany(companyId);
    }
```

Below is the Junit test

```
    @Transactional
        @DatabaseSetup(value = "EmployeeControllerIT.xml", type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT)
        public class EmployeeControllerIT extends SpringMvcIT {
          @Autowired
          EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Before
        public void setUpEmployeeControllerIT() {
    Set<Long> empIds = new HashSet<Long>();
            empIds.add(new Long("416908791"));
            empIds.add(new Long("416908790"));

            List<Employee> empList = empService.getEmpById(empIds);
            for (Employee emp : empList) {
                emp.setCreatedDate(new Date());
                emp.getAuditInfo().setCreatedBy(user);
                employeeService.saveOrUpdateEmployee(emp);
            }
    }
@Test
    public void shouldReturnFalseIncaseEmpCountIsReached2() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(
                get(EMPLOYEE_VALIDATION).param("action", "isEmployeeAllowed")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(jsonPath("$.isValidCount", is(false)));
    }
        }
```

Below is the controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employeeValidation.htm")
public class EmployeeValidationController {

    private static final String VALIDATE_EMPLOYEE_ELIGIBILITY = "action=isEmployeeAllowed";

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { VALIDATE_EMPLOYEE_ELIGIBILITY })
    public void validateEmployeeEligibility(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        Long count = employeeService.getEmpCountByCompany(Constant.COMPANY_ID)
        JSONObject employeeValidationObject = new JSONObject();
        boolean flag = true; 
        if(count>=2) {
            flag = false; 
        }
        employeeValidationObject.put("isValidCount", flag);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getOutputStream().write(employeeValidationObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a Debugger to find out if the Dates are what you expected?

Comment: I haven't used the debugger (can u pls point me to the link to know how to debug the testcase), but i put the sysout statements, which are displaying the expected dates

Comment: You are working with eclipse?

Comment: @Jens Yes, I'm working in eclipse and build tool is gradle

Comment: See this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html